# Different ways to work out the normal in the Frenet frame

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given a curve $\gamma (t) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, when working out the Frenet frame my lecture notes define the unit normal $$\tau : = \frac{\gamma ' (t)}{\| \gamma'(t)\|}$$ and then the principle unit normal as $$n : = \frac{\dot\tau}{\|\dot\tau\|}.$$

Surely it would give the same answer for the normal if I just calculated the unit normal by $$ n = \frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\|}?$$

Because differentiating $\tau$ is far more complicated, is this right?

**Edit**: So from the comments it would seem as if they aren't the same, and when trying to work it out as in @William's comment, I came out with a huge monster I couldn't simplify... but why (if so) aren't they the same? Surely it's just two different ways of working out the same formula; the formula for the unit normal at any particular point with respect to $t$. And there can't be two different unit normals..

Comment: Why don't you try? Differentiate $\tau$ and compare $\tau'/\|\tau'\|$ with $\gamma''/\|\gamma''\|$.

Comment: How do you differentiate $\tau$?

Comment: I guess that should have been your first question. Notice that $\|v(t)\|$, where $v$ is differentiable in $t$, is also a differentiable function. Assuming the norm is defined in the standard way, you get $\|v(t)\| = \sqrt{v_1^2(t) + \cdots + v_k^2(t)}$, where $v(t) = (v_1(t), \dots, v_k(t))$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$. On the other hand each $v_i$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: well it doesn't look like they're equating..

Comment: unless I'm not seeing an obvious simplification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't produce more formulas, but I can tell you why they aren't the same:

Given a parametric representation $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ of a curve $\gamma$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ the *velocity vector* $\gamma'(t)={d\gamma(t)\over dt}$ encodes information about the speed $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ of the moving point $\gamma(t)$ as well as information about the tangential direction of the curve $\gamma$ at the point $P=\gamma(t)$. The normalized vector $$\tau:=\gamma'(t)/\|\gamma'(t)\|=\dot\gamma$$
is the unit tangent vector to $\gamma$ at $P$.

The $\dot{}$ has the following meaning: Among all parametric representations ("timetables") of one and the same geometric curve $\gamma$ there is a distinguished one: the representation with respect to arc length $s$ along $\gamma$. This special representation is distinguished by the property $\|\dot\gamma\|=\left\|{d\gamma(s)\over ds}\right\|\equiv1$, and differentiation with respect to this special parameter is denoted by a $\cdot\ $.

The acceleration vector $\gamma''(t)$ encodes the infinitesimal change of the velocity vector $\gamma'(t)$. This change has a tangential component which is related to a change of *speed*, and a normal component which is related to a change of *direction*, and therewith to curvature. When you normalize this vector to $n^?:=\gamma''(t)/\|\gamma''(t)\|$ you get a certain unit vector incorporating information about speed change and direction change. Its physical or geometrical meaning is unclear.

On the other hand the vector $\tau:=\gamma'(t)/\|\gamma'(t)\|=\dot\gamma$  contains only information about the tangential direction of $\gamma$ at the point $P=\gamma(t)$, but no information about the speed with which the moving point passes the point $P$ . The vectors $\tau'={d\tau\over dt}$ and $\dot \tau={d\tau\over ds}$ therefore *only contain information about the change of direction* along $\gamma$, whereby $\tau'$ measures this change in relation to time and $\dot\tau$ in relation to arc length. The relation between $\dot\tau$ and $\tau'$ is given by
$$\dot\tau ={d\tau\over ds}={d\tau\over dt}\bigg/{ds\over dt}={\tau'\over\|\gamma'\|}\ .$$
In any case $\dot\tau$ is geometrically more relevant than $\tau'$; in fact $\|\dot\tau\|$ is the *curvature* of $\gamma$ at the point $P$.

The vector $n:={\dot\tau\over\|\dot\tau\|}$ is a unit vector pointing into the direction into which $\tau$ changes to. It is automatically orthogonal to $\tau$ since we took care to keep $\tau$ of unit length at all times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has made it much clearer. One thing: you've used both $\tau'$ and $\dot \tau$, what is the difference? I thought they were both just $\tau$ differentiated with respect to $t$?

Comment: @user53076: See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Let's show that $\frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\| }$ and $n$ are generally not the same vector.

By definition we know that
$$\gamma'(t) =\|\gamma'(t) \|\tau. \quad (1)$$
If we diferentiate $(1)$ we get
$$\gamma''(t) =\|\gamma'(t) \|'\tau +\|\gamma'(t) \|\tau'. \quad(2)$$
But by definition $\tau'=\|\tau'\|n$, so substituting in $(2)$ we get
$$\gamma''(t) =\|\gamma'(t) \|'\tau +\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|n. \quad(3)$$
Taking the norm of $\gamma''(t)$ we get
$$\|\gamma''(t)\| =\sqrt{(\|\gamma'(t) \|')^2+(\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|)^2}. \quad(4)$$
Using equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get
$$\frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\| } =\frac{\|\gamma'(t) \|'\tau +\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|n}{\sqrt{(\|\gamma'(t) \|')^2+(\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|)^2}}. \quad(5)$$
If $\|\gamma'(t) \|'=0$ we can conclude from $(5)$ that
$$\frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\| } = n$$
otherwise $\frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\| }$ and $n$ are not the same vector, since $\frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\| }$ will have two perpendicular components $\frac{\|\gamma'(t) \|'}{\sqrt{(\|\gamma'(t) \|')^2+(\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|)^2}}\tau$ and $\frac{\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|}{\sqrt{(\|\gamma'(t) \|')^2+(\|\gamma'(t) \|\|\tau'\|)^2}}n$.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a unit-speed parametrization of the curve, $\gamma'$ is the same as $\tau$ and you can use:
$$
n = \frac{\gamma''(t)}{\|\gamma''(t)\|}
$$

However, this is not true in general. To see why, compare the two values for $\gamma(t) = (t, \cosh t)$ which isn't a unit-speed parametrization.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to understand why this happens may be the basic principle that *the derivative of a vector function of unit length is always orthogonal to the function*; that is, if $|v(t)| =1$ for all $t$, $v(t)\cdot \dfrac{dv(t)}{dt} = 0$; you can prove this by differentiating the equation $|v(t)|^2=1$ and using the product rule.

By contrast, when a vector function *isn't* of unit (or more generally, constant) length, its temporal derivative has a component in the (pointwise) direction of the function, corresponding to the change in length.  This is why, to get a frame, it's important to normalize the tangent vector to the curve *before* differentiating it to get the normal; otherwise the normal won't actually be orthogonal to the tangent vector at points where the 'speed' of the curve changes.

More broadly, this leads to the concept of *parametrization invariance* which explains why we want the normalized versions in the first place: since we're concerned with properties of the *curve*, it shouldn't matter how fast we go along it.  That is, if our original curve is $\vec{\gamma}(t)$ (with tangent $\vec{\tau}(t)$ and normal $\vec{\nu}(t)$) and we define a new curve $\vec{\delta}(t)$ by $\vec{\delta}(t) = \vec{\gamma}(g(t))$ for some function $g(t)$, then we want the tangent to $\vec{\delta}$ to be given by $\vec{\tau}(g(t))$ and the normal to be given by $\vec{\nu}(g(t))$.  Unfortunately, if we try to take the normal by simply taking the second derivative and normalizing, the 'cross terms' in $g$ coming from the chain rule start to get in the way: $\vec{\delta}'(t)$ = $g'(t) \vec{\gamma}'(g(t))$, so $\vec{\delta}''(t)$ = $g''(t)\vec{\gamma}'(g(t))+\left(g'(t)\right)^2\vec{\gamma}''(g(t))$.  This is no longer a simple multiple of $\vec{\gamma}''$, so we can't get rid of the $g$-dependence just by normalizing it.

Answer (score 0):

For further beyond good answers above see the following books which are classic references on Differential geometry of curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$:  [Modern Differential Geometry of Curves And Surfaces With Mathematica](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=owEj9TMYo7IC&dq=differential%20geometry%20of%20curves%20and%20surfaces&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=M9b2UPvMGZK08ASNq4HwAg&sqi=2&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ) and **A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry** by [Michael Spivak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Spivak).